# Modificar posicion de elemento de manera responsive

Tags: html, css, materialize

utilizo materialicecss al utilizar un elemento navbar requiero que para la version del escritorio el logo se encuentre en la izquierda pero al ingresar desde un movil el logo debe de estar a la derecha.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Sin embargo cuando ingresa desde la version movil el logo se centra; materilizecss tiene una clase right que alinea el logo hacia donde quiero pero lo hace en todas las vistas. cuál sería la configuracion correcta para que una clase esté activa cuando se ingrese desde un movil y desactiva cuando no lo haga.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías usar `@media query` y jugar con el CSS para hacer lo que deseas, pero cuando utilizas un *framework* como Materialize me parece un poco innecesario añadir o modificar estilos y más si existen clases que hacen lo que necesitas.

En el apartado de [Helpers](https://materializecss.com/helpers.html) de la [documentación oficial](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) existe una sección llamada *Hiding/Showing Content* (Similar al *hide/show* de Bootstrap).

Verás que para el logo de la versión en escritorio uso las clases:
`.show-on-medium-and-up` y `.hide-on-med-and-down`

Mientras que para el logo de la versión móvil uso las clases:
`.show-on-small` y `.hide-on-med-and-up`

Creo que entendiendo un poco de inglés, sabrás el porqué uso esas clases predefinidas ;)

```html
<head>
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

</head>

<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="right brand-logo show-on-small hide-on-med-and-up">Logo</a>
    <a href="#" class="left brand-logo show-on-medium-and-up hide-on-med-and-down">Logo</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes aplicar css, para que no uses javascript, ahí un poco de flex.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.brand-logo{
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    text-align: right;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.brand-logo{
    width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    text-align: left;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
}
</style>
```